# How can I find base class properties that have their properties hidden by derived type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, reflection

I am developing a code generator that builds classes and then later has these classes serialized to XML through the `XmlSerializer`.

The problem is some of my base classes have defined properties but some of these properties will be hidden by derived types using the 'new' keyword in the derived types. This causes issues with serialization of the types because the Serializer doesn't allow for the types to be serialized unless the base type has an `[XmlIgnore]` attribute specified on the property that will be hidden by the derived type. The problem is that I do not know this until after I generate the code.

I was thinking that their must be a good way to use reflection to find all of the derived types of the base class I am generating and if any of the derived types hide the member or have a different custom attribute, then I would generate a `[XmlIgnore]` attribute on this property so that the serializer will not choke.

There must be a relatively simple way to do this as the compiler knows at compile time which base class properties are hidden and provides a warning if you are not specifying the 'new' keyword to tell the compiler that that is what is intended.

Any ideas of an elegant way that I could go about this?

Comment: You'll need to do it in two steps, because compilation of the derived classes isn't possible until code is available for the base class.  This still seems like a suboptimal solution though.  What if there are multiple classes deriving from the same base, and only some of them hide a property?

Comment: In my scenario that will not happen and even if it does I would be okay with it for now and handle it.

Comment: Right now I am attempting to do it in two steps. I am compiling the dll and then loading that assembly and using reflection to find the dervied types and members that are also defined in the derived types but it is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

From the `PropertyInfo` in the derived class, you'll need to follow the `GetMethod` and/or `SetMethod` properties to the `MethodInfo` of the actual implementation.

Then, check for the the [`NewSlot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute on the getter and setter.

This requires all the derived classes to be compiled and loaded, so you'll first have to generate the base class code once without this information.